# Django template filter to create an list of items that join on commas and end on "and"

Tags: django, django-templates

I feel like I am writing something that should already exist.

Does Django have a template filter that joins a list of items on commas and places and 'and' before the last one?

For example:

```
a = ['foo',]
b = ['bar', 'baz',]
c = a + b
d = c + ['yourmom',]
```

The filter I am looking for would display each list in the following ways:

> a would display 'foo'. 
>   b would display'bar and baz'.  
>   c would display 'foo, bar, and baz'.  
>   d would display 'foo, bar, baz, and yourmom'.

**QUESTION 1: Is there something that does that already?**

---

I tried to write this myself and it is breaking in two places:

My code:
http://pastie.org/private/fhtvg5tchtwlnrdyuoyeja

**QUESTION 2: It breaks on forloop.counter & tc.author.all|length. Please explain why these are not valid.**

Comment: What error are you getting at the `tc.author.all|length`? Also, instead of `|length` you could consider using `tc.author.all.count`

Comment: Your examples use the "Oxford comma," also known as the "Serial comma." That's the extra comma before the "and" in lists of three or more items. I.e., "foo, bar, and baz" is correct for two items, but "foo and bar" (with no comma) is correct for two. Fortunately, this is trivial to write a unit test for. The solutions so far below all fail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it in your template:

```
{% for item in list %}
    {% if forloop.first %}{% else %}
        {% if forloop.last %} and {% else %}, {% endif %}
    {% endif %}{{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

*line breaks added for clarity: remove them in order to avoid unwanted blank spaces in your output:*

```
{% for item in list %}{% if forloop.first %}{% else %}{% if forloop.last %} and {% else %}, {% endif %}{% endif %}{{item}}{% endfor %}
```

**Edit:** Changed code. Thanks to Eric Fortin for making me notice that I was confused.

Comment: Actually, I think it needs to be reversed like so:

{% if forloop.last %} and {% else %}, {% endif %}{{item}} and we also need a first if to check for first element to avoid displaying "foo and" for the first example.

So: {% if forloop.first %}{{item}}{% else %}{% if forloop.last %} and {% else %}, {% endif %}{{item}}{% endif %}

Comment: Thanks for posting. I feel lame. I think I over thought it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I wrote with a "max items" feature:

```
useserialcomma = True

def listify(values, maxitems=4):
    sercomma = ',' if useserialcomma else ''
    l = len(values)
    if l == 0:
        return ''
    elif l == 1:
        return values[0]
    elif l == 2:
        return values[0] + ' and ' + values[1]
    elif l <= maxitems:
        return ', '.join(values[:l-1]) + sercomma + ' and ' + values[-1]
    else:
        andmoretxt = ' and %d more' % (l - maxitems)
        return ', '.join(values[:maxitems]) + andmoretxt
```

This filter lets you specify the maximum number of items you'd like to display. So, given this list:

```
myitems = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'barn', 'feast', 'pizza']
```

this code in your template:

```
{{ myitems|listify:3 }}
```

produces:

```
foo, bar, baz and 3 others
```

Answer (score -1):

Try a filter like this (not tested):

```
def human_join(values):
    out = ', '.join(values[:-1])
    if out:
        out += ' and '

    if values:
        out += values[-1]

    return out
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem using css `::before` and `::after` pseudo-classes. I gave each item an `item` class, and then did this:

```
.item:not(:last-child)::after{
    content: ", ";
}
.item:last-child::before{
    content: "and ";
}
.item:last-child::after{
    content: ".";
}
```

It's not a Django solution, but it is always good to stir the pot of ideas.